# How much power does an NVIDIA GeForce 210 actually use?

Tags: graphics-card, power

[This spec](https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/EN210_SILENTDI1GD3V2LP/specifications/) says the NVIDIA GeForce 210 uses "up to 75W." Does that mean "mostly 75W" or "when I'm reading crap on the Internet (90% of the time) it's 10W"?

I want to buy it, but I don't want the equivalent of a bright incandescent bulb on all the time, because I'm an earth hugger.  If it's 10W, seems buyable.

Moved from [gaming stackexchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293320/how-much-power-does-an-nvidia-geforce-210-actually-use) at their request.

Comment: Power usage cannot be predicted based on the information you have provided

Comment: What information would I have to provide? That's all I have. Feel free to answer a more limited question: what is minimum power usage? what is average given some workload?

Comment: Power Usage is based on the applications you run

Comment: Sure, but there's no way to accurately summarize that in a question. How about other peoples' experience with this graphics card running different applications? Anything. This is not an unanswerable question, it doesn't require such precision.

Comment: Why would you buy a 210 (about 8+ year old tech) when a more recent 710 costs about the same, has a much lower power ceiling (30W rather than 75) and probably has much better performance for most modern tasks?  As Ramhound says though, it's difficult to know the power usage without knowing what you're doing with it.  Static unchanging screens? Probably about 10% their rated power. Playing videos & Internet, maybe 10 to 20%.  Playing demanding games, probably nearer their upper limit.

Comment: @dfrankow Our experiences makes a horrible Q&A answer.  Modify the question so our answer makes a good Q&A answer

Comment: @mokubai because I want something without a fan.

Comment: @ramhound Open to suggestions.

Comment: @dfrankow i don't have any suggestions

Comment: @Mokubai Just found fanless 710. It is more expensive ($43 versus $18) but still very useful information. Thank you!